# Python CGI script - 500 error

Tags: python, apache, cgi

I have python CGI script that runs perfect on my local Apache 2.2.22 server. It outputs correct result and so on. But when I try to execute it on virtual hosting, there is error 500.
I really have no idea why it does not works.

Apache error log looks like:

```
[Wed Jul 12 16:06:54 2013] [error] [client 89.223.235.12] Premature end of script headers: /home/u67442/rrrrr.com/cgi-bin/test.py
[Wed Jul 12 16:09:31 2013] [error] [client 89.223.235.12] Premature end of script headers: /home/u67442/rrrrr.com/cgi-bin/test.py
```

I've already tried following things:

1. I'm sure that path to interpreter is correct - `#!/usr/local/bin/python`. Another CGI script works fine with this path.
2. I have set chmod 755 to this script.
3. I have set end-of-line characters in UNIX-format.
4. I use correct HTTP-header: `print "Content-type:text/html\n\n"`

Output section of script:

```
    print "Content-type:text/html\n\n"
    print "<html>"
    print "<head>"
    print "<title>Results</title>"
    print "<head><h2 align=center>Results</h2></head>"
    print "</head>"
    print '<body bgcolor="#e8f3d8">'
    print "<hr>"
    print "<b>Result = %s </b>" % str(round(total_sum, 5))
    print "</body>"
    print "</html>"
```

Funny that another VERY similar script with the same path, header, EOL, output and so on works perfect on local server and virtual hosting. And it's very strange that this script works fine on my local apache, but on virtual web hosting it crashes with 500 internal server error. I really don't know what to do. In technical support says that there is problem in my script.

There is only one idea - timeout of waiting of output. Data processing in my script takes about 15-25 seconds.

What can you advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Problem was in the script. I replace function for data extraction from *.dat files from one of 'while' loops.
Anyway, I still do not understand why it worked on local server and didn't worked on virtual hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Check your error_log.
If you can, run the script from the command line of the virtual host.
If you can, su - webserveruser and do it again.
Are you trying to import a module that is not present on the server?
Does the webserver process have permission to fetch the data that ends up in total_sum?
To narrow down the problem, try hard-coding a value for total_sum and commenting out the code that fetches data and computes it. Does the rest work then?
Does the virtual host run the same version of python as your local server? If not, check that your code works in both versions.